# Hibernate lazy для коллекций

Tags: hibernate

Как я понял при использовании ленивой загрузки для коллекций - ВСЯ коллекция загружается по требованию, если объект не `detached` (Я ведь правильно понимаю?).

В рассматриваемом варианте имеется, допустим, `Map<Integer, SomeObject>`,
причем `Map` имеет достаточно много значений, но часто используется лишь некоторые из этих значений, можно ли как-то сделать ленивую загрузку только требуемых элементов, т.е при загрузке выбирать все ключи, а объекты загружать по мере необходимости?

Answer (score 0):

Первое утверждение верно.
А второе нет. Вы не можете выгрузить из мапы только ключи. Но вы можете установить @BatchSize(size=10). Это значит что коллекция будет выгружать к примеру порциями по 10, а не вся сразу